# Does the EU-Japan trade agreement include ISDS?

Tags: european-union, japan, trade

The EU and Japan have [signed a trade agreement](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-40520218).  In other trade agreements, such as CETA and TTIP, a (highly) contentious issue is [Investor-state dispute-settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investor-state_dispute_settlement) (ISDS), in which private courts may award damages to companies if a country adopts legislation that has a negative economic impact on a particular company (such as environmental, health, or labour protections).  The BBC article makes no mention of ISDS.  Is this included in the EU-Japan trade deal?

Answer (score 7):

According to [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2017/jul/06/japan-and-eu-expected-to-sign-trade-deal-after-breakthrough-in-talks), this is still open.  Apparently, both the EU and Japan want some form of trade court, but the exact form remains under discussion:

> Despite a likely agreement on Thursday, the sensitive subject of a court system to settle investor disputes remains open. Japan has not accepted the EU’s preferred alternative to the investor-state dispute settlement (ISDS), a system for resolving trade disputes that has been criticised by unions and activists for giving too much power to corporations. Under pressure from NGOs, the EU proposed a new kind of trade court, where judges would be appointed by governments rather than disputing parties. But Tokyo has not come round to this idea.